# Ubuntu android sdk crashing

Tags: ubuntu, android-sdk-tools

I have tried to use the 32bit and 64bit versions of the sdk and the 32bit is not working at all(as i expected, as i am on a 64bit system). But when i use 64bit it crashes after doing certain things such as prompting certain auto-completes from the IDE.

Below is the report generated from the crash.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7d3b85a2a1, pid=4970, tid=140179243480832
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b14) (build 1.7.0_55-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on KDE try switching the GTK2 theme to anything not Oxygen related (I'm using Raleigh). It'll still crash and be a pain, and as an added bonus some other application will look ugyly, but it'll be far more stable.